# Can't edit xsp.properties file in the UI mode in domino designer 9.0 (not the plain text mode via package explorer - this is fine)

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib, domino-designer-eclipse

Problem: I can't edit the xsp.properties file in the UI edit window (I know I can edit it manually from the package explorer)

I believe I am getting this problem due to the following error that I find in the Help/Support/View Trace of Domino Designer (9.0) .. though I am not 100% sure:

Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com/ibm/xsp/extlib/designer/common/properties/AppThemeLookup.theme_Standard_Ids
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.xspprops.XSPPage.(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.xspprops.XSPParentEditor.createPages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.ui.internal.presentations.FolderStackPresentation.selectPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.presentationSelectionChanged(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.access$1(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.selectPart(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.ui.internal.presentations.FolderStackPresentation$4.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder.onMouse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.swt.swidgets.STabFolder$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPApplication.run(Unknown Source)

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.startLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
```

Related to the above error I was also getting:  Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface", especially in relation to the "Relational" feature of the ext lib.    org.openntf.extlib.relational.feature   I just disabled that feature to get past that error (which is not really a solution), but I still have the java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com/ibm/xsp/extlib/designer/common/properties/AppThemeLookup.theme_Standard_Ids

Has anyone come across this? Or is there a solution to fix this? (short of uninstalling the extlib, or just going back to editing the tsp.properties file manually via package explorer)

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to install latest ext lib?
You may try to remove the Data\workspace folder contents. This might solve issue.

Comment: Avoid removing the data\workspace folder unless absolutely necessary. It removes *all* Eclipse-related settings from Notes/Designer - working sets, plugins, preferences etc. There are blog posts about backing up certain elements and widget catalogs can store plugin settings. ExtLib may resolve the problem, but remember to use the -designer versions. These have the DDE tooling specific to the client.

Comment: Removing the Data/workspace folder does indeed allow me to see the xsp.properties in the UI, but only because it effectively removes the extension library from being installed.  

I did indeed use the -designer version for installing the ExtLib V17 which is the latest. 

I hadn't yet tried installing the latest designer client (9.0.1) since I'd have to install a trial version, but I did wonder if my 9.0 designer client had some mismatch with the extlib.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading my 9.0 designer client with the 9.0.1 version of designer, and as *hoped* it did indeed fix the issue. ie I can now edit the xsp.properties in the UI as well as having the extlib (V17) installed.